# Sending mail using python on specific days

Tags: python, email

***Requirement*** : I need to store information regarding birthdays of certain people and send mail to all on each birthday.

I have done the following :

**Wrote python script to send html file to all the people. It reads the following :**

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

me = "hunter@gmail.com"
you = "prudhvi@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

html = """\ 
<html>
<body>

<b>HAPPY BIRTHDAY SHERLYN<br></b>

</body>
</html>
"""

part = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part)

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login('username', 'password')
mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

**Also wrote the following script to print the name of the birthday boy on particular day :**

```
import email
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
a = now.strftime("%d-%B")

birthdays = {
             '09-December': ['BOB'],
             '10-December': ['JOHN'],
             '16-December': ['SHERLYN'],

            } 

today_birthdays = birthdays.get(a)

if today_birthdays:
    for person in today_birthdays:
        print "Happy Birthday %s!" % person
else:
    print "No Birthday today"
```

The first statement in the second script : ***import email*** is the name of the python file containing the email code. So, whenever I run the above script, the email is being sent everyday [without considering birthdays], as I imported the email python file in it.

1.) I want it to send an email only on birthdays and not on other days.

2.) In my html code, I want the name to change according to the birthday . 
Ex : On Sherlyn's birthday, it should send Happy Birthday Sherlyn

3.) In my first code, I am trying to send the email from a Gmail account.
So, I used :

```
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

But, what if I have to send it from company mail?

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to send to a different email address for each person. You could do that with a separate dictionary of `name: address`, assuming there are no duplicate names.

1.) In your `email.py`, you should move all of that code into a function, so that an email is only sent when you call the function. At the moment all the code is in the global scope in that module, so it's executed when you `import` it, not when you want to send an email. You might also consider having the function take a name and email address as an argument:

```
def send_email(name, address):
    # Skipped the rest of the contents, as they're the same... 
    # just the sending line:
    mail.sendmail(me, address, msg.as_string())
```

Then from your second script, you would call `email.send_email(person, address)`

2.) The thing you want to look up is called string formatting, and the `.format` method. For this one, you could do:

```
html = """\ 
<html>
<body>

<b>HAPPY BIRTHDAY {name}<br></b>

</body>
</html>
"""
```

Then to fill it in:

```
html.format(name="Sherlyn")
html.format(name="Bob")
```

3.) will depend on how your company email is set up, you might need to ask your service desk or helpdesk for the smtp details.

Comment: I have done what you have asked me to. I get the email this way :    **HAPPY BIRTHDAY {name}**

Comment: are you calling the format() method? `part = MIMEText(html.format(name=name), 'html')` or something similar?